# highlighted space display

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a question concerning vscode. A very simple one. why do I have highlighted text in python code (jupyter) as in the photo joined ? How can I cancel it ?
[image]

Comment: disable your extensions and see which one does the coloring

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@installed` to view the installed extensions in the extension store.

Disabling the extensions related to this function can solve this problem.